# ¿Cómo tomar elementos de un XML y me los imprima mediante un objeto?

Tags: java, xml, poo

He creado esta clase principal que me imprime directo los elementos de un xml según la etiqueta que le diga:

```
File xmlFile = new File("C:\\XML\\conceptos.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Pieza");

        for(int i=0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

         Node node = list.item(i);

         if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

          Element element = (Element) node;

          System.out.println("Posicion: "+element.getElementsByTagName("Posicion").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println("Numero Parte: "+element.getElementsByTagName("NumeroParte").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println("Descripcion: "+element.getElementsByTagName("Descripcion").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println("Monto: "+element.getElementsByTagName("Monto").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println("Cambio Precio: "+element.getElementsByTagName("CambioPrecio").item(0).getTextContent());
```

Pero necesito arrojar esos datos a un objeto y luego imprimirlos.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero podrías crear una clase donde almacenar tus objetos.

*Concepto.java*

```
public class Concepto {
    private String posicion;
    private String numeroParte;
    private String descripcion;
    private String monto;
    private String cambioPrecio;

    // getters y setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Concepto{" +
            "posicion='" + posicion + '\'' +
            ", numeroParte='" + numeroParte + '\'' +
            ", descripcion='" + descripcion + '\'' +
            ", monto='" + monto + '\'' +
            ", cambioPrecio='" + cambioPrecio + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Después crear un `new ArraList<Concepto>()` para almacenar cada uno de los objetos en un arreglo y utilizarlo de esta forma:

```
...
Concepto concepto = new Concepto();
List<Concepto> conceptos = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    concepto.setPosicion(element.getElementsByTagName("Posicion").item(0).getTextContent());
    concepto.setNumeroParte(...);
    concepto.setDescripcion(...);
    concepto.setMonto(...);
    concepto.setCambioPrecio(...);
    conceptos.add(concepto);
}
...
```

Adicional te puede podría interesar revisar esta pregunta por si deseas utilizar otro método para pasar de un archivo XML a un Objeto en java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364653/6415698

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Agregue el cuerpo del método `toString()` para imprimir el contenido del objeto el cual puedes utilizar en tu programa de la siguiente forma:

`System.out.println(concepto.toString());`

Comment: Al querer imprimir, agregue esto: System.out.println(concepto); pero no me imprime los datos, solo me lanza muchas veces Concepto@a987ac

Comment: Si quieres imprimir el contenido del objeto necesitas sobreescribir el método `toString()` en la clase *Concepto.java* con lo que desees que imprima. Actualizo la respuesta con el cuerpo del método a implementar.

Comment: TE LO AGRADEZCO MONTONES!!

FUNCIONO!!